# Checking a condition on a matrix in Matlab?

Tags: matlab, matrix

I have the following matrix on Matlab and I want to check a condition. Could you help me to write a piece of code doing it? The matrix is

```
   %A5  M5  A6  M6  A7  M7  A8  M8
   %-----------------------------
 C=[0   1   0   2   0   3   0   4;
    0   2   0   3   0   4   0   5;
    0   3   0   4   0   5   0   6;
    0   4   0   5   0   6   0   7;
    1   5   1   6   1   7   1   8;
    1   5   1   6   1   7   2   1;
    1   5   1   6   1   7   0   1;
    1   5   1   6   2   1   2   2;
    1   5   1   6   2   1   3   1;
    1   5   1   6   2   1   0   1;
    1   5   1   6   0   1   0   2;
    1   5   2   1   2   2   2   3;
    1   5   2   1   2   2   3   1;
    1   5   2   1   2   2   0   1;
    1   5   2   1   3   1   3   2;
    1   5   2   1   3   1   0   1;
    1   5   2   1   0   1   0   2;
    1   5   0   1   0   2   0   3;
    2   1   2   2   2   3   2   4;
    2   1   2   2   2   3   3   1;
    2   1   2   2   2   3   0   1;
    2   1   2   2   3   1   3   2;
    2   1   2   2   3   1   0   1;
    2   1   2   2   0   1   0   2;
    2   1   3   1   3   2   3   3;
    2   1   3   1   3   2   0   1;
    2   1   3   1   0   1   0   2;
    2   1   0   1   0   2   0   3;
    2   2   2   3   2   4   2   5;
    2   2   2   3   2   4   1   1;
    2   2   2   3   2   4   0   1;
    2   2   2   3   3   1   3   2;
    2   2   2   3   3   1   0   1;
    2   2   2   3   0   1   0   2;
    2   2   3   1   3   2   3   3;
    2   2   3   1   3   2   0   1;
    2   2   3   1   0   1   0   2;
    2   2   0   1   0   2   0   3;
    2   3   2   4   2   5   2   6;
    2   3   2   4   2   5   3   1;
    2   3   2   4   2   5   0   1;
    2   3   2   4   3   1   3   2;
    2   3   2   4   3   1   0   1;
    2   3   2   4   0   1   0   2;
    2   3   3   1   3   2   3   3;
    2   3   3   1   3   2   0   1;
    2   3   3   1   0   1   0   2;
    2   3   0   1   0   2   0   3;
    2   4   2   5   2   6   2   7;
    2   4   2   5   2   6   3   1;
    2   4   2   5   2   6   0   1;
    2   4   2   5   3   1   3   2;
    2   4   2   5   3   1   0   1;
    2   4   2   5   0   1   0   2;
    2   4   3   1   3   2   3   3;
    2   4   3   1   3   2   0   1;
    2   4   3   1   0   1   0   2;
    2   4   0   1   0   2   0   3;
    3   1   3   2   3   3   3   4;
    3   1   3   2   3   3   0   1;
    3   1   3   2   0   1   0   2;
    3   1   0   1   0   2   0   3;
    3   2   3   3   3   4   3   5;
    3   2   3   3   3   4   0   1;
    3   2   3   3   0   1   0   2;
    3   2   0   1   0   2   0   3;
    3   3   3   4   3   5   3   6;
    3   3   3   4   3   5   0   1;
    3   3   3   4   0   1   0   2;
    3   3   0   1   0   2   0   3]
```

I called the columns `A5 M5 A6 M6 A7 M7 A8 M8`

Here the condition I want to check: I want to find the values of `A6,M6,A7,M7` (if any) such that

(1) `M4` takes at least `4` distinct values

**and** [same time]

(2) `M8` takes at least `4` distinct values

Comment: use `numel(unique(C(:,column)))` to get the unique values in a column

Comment: If the conditions are satisfied for a subset of the rows, they are also statisfied for all rows. Do you want a minimal subset of the rows, a random subset or all rows?

Comment: Which column is `M4`?

Answer (score 0):

This code run in a script accomplishes what you want:

```
% Relevant Columns of C
M4 = 1; % Assuming M4 was some typo
M8 = 8;
cols = 3:6;

if numel(unique(C(:,M4))) >= 4 && numel(unique(C(:,M8))) >= 4
    A = C(:,cols);
end
```